# Convert String to NSDecimalNumber

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsdecimalnumber

I try to convert a String into a NSDecimalNumber here it my code:

```
class func stringToDecimal (dataToDecimal: String) -> NSDecimalNumber {

    let dataToDecimal = dataToDecimal.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: ".")
    print(dataToDecimal)
    let  decimalReturn = NSDecimalNumber(string: dataToDecimal)
    print(decimalReturn)

    if decimalReturn == NSDecimalNumber.notANumber(){
        return 0.00
    }
    return decimalReturn
}
```

First I thought that maybe the , is wrong but even with . it doesn't work. 
The first print (before converting) shows e.g 80,00 but the print(decimalReturn) shows only 80

the if line is the just to check if the result is not a number.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use an `NSNumberFormatter` to parse your input. Set its `generatesDecimalNumbers` property to true:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
```

Here's how you use it, if you want to return 0 when the string can't be parsed:

```
func decimal(with string: String) -> NSDecimalNumber {
    return formatter.number(from: string) as? NSDecimalNumber ?? 0
}

decimal(with: "80.00")

// Result: 80 as an NSDecimalNumber
```

By default, the formatter will look at the device's locale setting to determine the decimal marker. You should leave it that way. For the sake of example, I'll force it to a French locale:

```
// DON'T DO THIS. Just an example of behavior in a French locale.
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr-FR")

decimal(with: "80,00")
// Result: 80

decimal(with: "80.00")
// Result: 0
```

If you really want to always use a comma as the decimal mark, you can set the `decimalSeparator` property:

```
formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
```

Comment: it worked, but I had to do the  `let dataToDecimal = dataToDecimal.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: ".")` first, to bring my string to get not nil. If I just try a string with a "," it will bring nil as result.

Comment: I ve read that NSDecimal is precise for calculation, but if I take 80.01 the outcome is 80.01000002 if I take 80.10 it s 80.09999999. How would you reduce the digits to 2?

Comment: You'll have to show your code. It would be best to do so as a new question.

Comment: I wonder, how is this different from `Decimal(string: "80,00", locale: Locale.current)`?

Comment: `Decimal(string:locale:)` was not added until iOS 10 and macOS 10.12 in 2016.

Comment: @robmayoff I don't believe that's true. `NSDecimalNumber` had that initializer always. If you notice, all `Decimal` methods are marked as `iOS 10+`.

Comment: You're right. I was looking at the Swift docs, and everything in the `Decimal` class is available as of the 2016 OS versions.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with the way you are creating a `NSDecimalNumber` from a `String`. However, you might not need to worry about replacing the comma with a period if that is how your local formats numbers.

The reason it prints 80 instead of 80,00 or 80.00 is that `print` just uses the `description` property of the number. If you want to customize the formatting, you should setup your own `NSNumberFormatter`.

```
let number = NSDecimalNumber(string: "80.00")
print(number) // 80
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
let string = formatter.stringFromNumber(number)
print(string) // 80.0
```

Comment: I tried out, but in real project and  playground it brings an error message "Cannot convert value of type "String" to expected argument type "NSNumber" but the ...minimumFractions I like and will play with that.

Comment: It's possible there is another problem in your code then. The code I posted works fine in a playground.

Answer (score 0):

When server forces some certain locale use that instead of Locale.current
lest you want breakage depending on the user's settings

```
extension String {
    var decimalFromServerString: NSDecimalNumber? {
        let parsed = NSDecimalNumber(string: self, locale: ru_ru_posix)
        if parsed == .notANumber {
            return nil
        }
        return parsed
    }
}
```

PS. if you hardcore locale to en_US POSIX for some reason string "..." comes out as 0. Go figure :-[

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the number has comma thousands separators in it